# Editing Image Texture from Blenderkit in Photoshop

Tags: texturing, blenderkit

I’d like to edit a texture I found on Blenderkit. Is there a way to export or direct to where the texture image is in my computer so I can edit it on Photoshop?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you select the texture in Blender and open the Shader editor you'll see all the textures used (base Color, Roughness, etc.)  Click on the R/H icon against the filename on the Base Color texture node (to the left of the 'x' close icon below the Alpha output) and it will offer to unpack that texture to a folder location. You can then edit it externally if you want.